# Removing user access to some directories

Tags: centos, access-control

In my Unix system, there is a user which has access to multiple (but not all) subdirectories of /home/. How can I remove access to most directories for this user? I've looked in /etc/groups, but didn't find much useful info in there. The system is CentOS 6.7.

Would appreciate a clue. I've looked up online, but have so far not found particularly useful information for my case, in spite of having spent a good deal of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User Directory Permissions ?

## Solution:

Let's assume that you have this directory:

**/home/office/files**

**Of course you would wanted only Staff to have access to it.**

On your *nix box, you've created *staff* as group, and assigned staff to *staff* group.

To know which group a user belong to, you don't need to expose your /etc/passwd file, just issue this command:

```
root@Hosts:~# id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),2001(ftpgroup)
```

`id username`, gives information about the user in question
or `finger username` gives more information about a user such as **login name, directory etc.**

However, the following commands ensure that any user not in **staff** group will not have access to **/home/office/files**

```
chown -R myuser:staff /home/office
chmod 750 /home/office
```

Replace **myuser** with username to have access and **staff** with groupname to have access to the folder.

### NJOY

Answer (score 2):

Well you can check in `/etc/group` and check the group that the user belongs to.

Accordingly, you can change the folder you want to restrict's ownership to either **root** so only **root** can access the folder, or to a **different user**. Using `sudo chown -R root:root <directory name>` or `sudo chown -R user:group <directory name>` and change the folder's permissions to `750` using the command `sudo chmod 750 <folder name>`.

The `chmod` command will make sure only the `user` and `group` owner of the folder have access to the file's inside the folder.

EDIT:

Your `/etc/group` shows that you only have the root user on your system.

The **root** user has access to all files and folders in your entire system. You cannot restrict access to the root user.

You can create a normal user using the command `adduser <username>`. This user will have access only to the files and folders that user owns.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no information in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` to which group a user belongs.

The format is like this:

`user:x:500:500::/home/user:/bin/bash`

Comment: Care to add your `/etc/group` to your question?

Comment: There should be a Group list after `user:x:500:500::/home/user:/bin/bash, ...`

Comment: `root:x:0:root
bin:x:1:root,bin,daemon
daemon:x:2:root,bin,daemon
sys:x:3:root,bin,adm
adm:x:4:root,adm,daemon
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:root
lp:x:7:daemon,lp
mem:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:root
mail:x:12:mail,postfix,opendkim`

Comment: It looks like you have no user on your system except root. can you show me the output of `who`

Comment: I showed just a segment of the file to show the format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64572/discussion-between-hunter-s-thompson-and-sequence).